# Could not find archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm using [kitchenplan](https://github.com/kitchenplan/kitchenplan) (a variant of `chef-solo`) to try adding [chef-rvm](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm) cookbook and use it, but I have this weird error on `archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2` and I'm not sure what am I missing.

Not sure whether this is related to chef-rvm or kitchenplan, but it doesn't seem to work again after few days with no change.

I'm running this on the Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

**Kitchenplan yaml config**:

```
@@ -20,6 +20,7 @@ recipes:
         - applications::openssl
+        - applications::rvm
     mac_os_x:
         - applications::ios-sim
+attributes:
+    rvm:
+      version: 1.24.7
+      rubies:
+        - 
+      default_ruby: 1.9.3-p484
```

**Error logs**:

```
[2013-12-19T15:58:05-08:00] INFO: Processing log[Performing RVM install with [curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash  -s -- --version 1.24.8] (as root)] action write (rvm::system_install line 76)
[2013-12-19T15:58:05-08:00] INFO: Performing RVM install with [curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash  -s -- --version 1.24.8] (as root)
  * log[Performing RVM install with [curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash  -s -- --version 1.24.8] (as root)] action write

[2013-12-19T15:58:05-08:00] INFO: Processing execute[install system-wide RVM] action run (rvm::system_install line 78)
  * execute[install system-wide RVM] action runDownloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.24.8.tar.gz

Installing RVM to /usr/local/rvm/
Installation of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is almost complete:

  * First you need to add all users that will be using rvm to 'rvm' group,
    and logout - login again, anyone using rvm will be operating with `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`.

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# OSX Builder,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] INFO: execute[install system-wide RVM] ran successfully

    - execute curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash  -s -- --version 1.24.8

[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] DEBUG: Skipping execute[upgrade system-wide RVM to none] due to not_if ruby block
Recipe: rvm::system
[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] INFO: Processing rvm_ruby[1.9.3-p484] action install (rvm::system line 176)
[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] DEBUG: Fetching canonical RVM string for: 1.9.3-p484 (system)
  * rvm_ruby[1.9.3-p484] action install[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] DEBUG: Canonical RVM string is: 1.9.3-p484 => ruby-1.9.3-p484 (system)
[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T15:58:11-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'list' 'strings'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T15:58:14-08:00] INFO: Building rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p484], this could take a while...
[2013-12-19T15:58:14-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T15:58:14-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T15:58:14-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 'install' 'ruby-1.9.3-p484'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:13-08:00] INFO: Installation of rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p484] was successful.
[2013-12-19T16:06:13-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T16:06:13-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:13-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'use' 'ruby-1.9.3-p484'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:16-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T16:06:16-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:16-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'list' 'strings'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:20-08:00] INFO: Importing initial gemsets for rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p484]
[2013-12-19T16:06:20-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T16:06:20-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:20-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'gemset' 'initial'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: Initial gemsets for rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p484] are installed
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] INFO: rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p484] build time was 8.44972958333333 minutes.


[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] INFO: Processing rvm_default_ruby[1.9.3-p484] action create (rvm::system line 184)
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
  * rvm_default_ruby[1.9.3-p484] action create[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [export rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [rvm 'use' 'default'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:41-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'list' 'default' 'string'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:45-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T16:06:45-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:45-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [export rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:45-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:45-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [rvm 'use' 'default'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:45-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'list' 'strings'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] INFO: Setting default ruby to rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p484]
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [export rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [rvm 'use' 'default'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:49-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'use' 'ruby-1.9.3-p484' '--default'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]


[2013-12-19T16:06:53-08:00] INFO: Processing rvm_global_gem[bundler] action install (rvm::system line 190)
  * rvm_global_gem[bundler] action installRecipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>
[2013-12-19T16:06:53-08:00] INFO: Processing execute[Add bundler to /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/global.gems] action run (/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb line 79)
  * execute[Add bundler to /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/global.gems] action run (skipped due to not_if)
[2013-12-19T16:06:53-08:00] DEBUG: Skipping execute[Add bundler to /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/global.gems] due to not_if command `grep -q "^bundler" "/usr/local/rvm/gemsets/global.gems"`
[2013-12-19T16:06:54-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper subprocess executing with environment of: [{}].
[2013-12-19T16:06:54-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.11.3.8/lib/rvm/shell/shell_wrapper.sh'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:54-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [export rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:54-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:54-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper silently executing: [rvm 'use' 'default'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:54-08:00] DEBUG: RVM::Shell::ChefWrapper executing: [rvm 'list' 'strings'; __rvm_show_command_epilog]
[2013-12-19T16:06:57-08:00] INFO: Processing rvm_gem[bundler] action install (/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb line 48)
[2013-12-19T16:06:57-08:00] DEBUG: rvm_gem[bundler] using gem from running ruby environment
  * rvm_gem[bundler] action install
1.24.8

[2013-12-19T16:06:58-08:00] DEBUG: RVM version = 1.24.8 (system)

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'rvm_gem[bundler]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
---- End output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
Ran bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" returned 1


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/rvm_rubygems_package.rb:64:in `gem_paths'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:57:in `gem_package_wrapper'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:35:in `class_from_file'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:34:in `each'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:34:in `class_from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb

 48:   g = rvm_gem new_resource.package_name do
 49:     ruby_string ruby_global_gemset
 50:     source      new_resource.source if new_resource.source
 51:     options     new_resource.options if new_resource.options
 52:     version     new_resource.version if new_resource.version
 53:     gem_binary  new_resource.gem_binary if new_resource.gem_binary
 54:     user        new_resource.user
 55:     action      :nothing
 56:   end
 57:   g.run_action(exec_action)



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:48:in `gem_package_wrapper'

rvm_gem("bundler") do
  cookbook_name :rvm
  ruby_string "ruby-1.9.3-p484@global"
  package_name "bundler"
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::RVMRubygems
  gem_binary "gem"
  retry_delay 2
  action [:nothing]
  retries 0
end




================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'rvm_global_gem[bundler]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
rvm_gem[bundler] (/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb line 48) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
---- End output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
Ran bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" returned 1


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/rvm_rubygems_package.rb:64:in `gem_paths'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:57:in `gem_package_wrapper'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:35:in `class_from_file'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:34:in `each'
/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:34:in `class_from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/chef_rvm_recipe_helpers.rb

190:           rvm_global_gem gem[:name] do
191:             user      opts[:user]
192:             [:version, :action, :options, :source].each do |attr|
193:               send(attr, gem[attr]) if gem[attr]
194:             end
195:           end
196:         end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/chef_rvm_recipe_helpers.rb:190:in `install_rubies'

rvm_global_gem("bundler") do
  cookbook_name :rvm
  package_name "bundler"
  recipe_name "system"
  retry_delay 2
  action :install
  retries 0
end



[2013-12-19T16:06:59-08:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2013-12-19T16:06:59-08:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed - rvm_global_gem[bundler] (rvm::system line 190) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: rvm_gem[bundler] (/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb line 48) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
---- End output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
Ran bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" returned 1
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.3.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:253:in `invalid!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.3.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:239:in `error!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:45:in `shell_out!'
  /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/rvm_rubygems_package.rb:64:in `gem_paths'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:297:in `gem_source_index'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:98:in `installed_versions'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:454:in `matching_installed_versions'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:437:in `current_version'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:470:in `load_current_resource'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:97:in `run_action'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:625:in `run_action'
  /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:57:in `gem_package_wrapper'
  /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:35:in `class_from_file'
  /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:34:in `each'
  /opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb:34:in `class_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:138:in `action_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:118:in `send'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:118:in `run_action'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/chef-11.8.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:625:in `run_action'
....
....

Chef Client failed. 51 resources updated
[2013-12-19T16:06:59-08:00] ERROR: rvm_global_gem[bundler] (rvm::system line 190) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: rvm_gem[bundler] (/opt/kitchenplan/cookbooks/rvm/providers/global_gem.rb line 48) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
---- End output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" ----
Ran bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm ruby-1.9.3-p484@global do gem env gempath" returned 1
[2013-12-19T16:06:59-08:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo bin/chef-solo --log_level debug -c solo.rb -j kitchenplan-attributes.json -o applications::create_var_chef_cache,applications::google-chrome,applications::firefox,applications::java,dotfiles::kms,dotfiles::workspace,applications::postgresql,applications::psycopg2,applications::mysql,applications::mysql_python,applications::apache,applications::git,applications::wget,applications::pwgen,applications::xmlstarlet,applications::pv,applications::htop,dotfiles::gitconfig,applications::grunt-cli,applications::bower,applications::git-flow,applications::sass,applications::siege,applications::nodejs,applications::ssh_config,dotfiles::vim,applications::composer,applications::tmux,applications::rvm,applications::bash-completion,dotfiles::bash_it,dotfiles::inputrc
Failed during: ./kitchenplan -d
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that script is attempting to use the system Rubygems (at `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/`) instead of the Rubygems install with RVM (1.9.3). This is likely a bug in the RVM cookbook.

I'm not entirely familiar with Kitchenplan, but I would suggest trying to use the cookbook with regular Chef Solo or [Test Kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen). If that succeeds, you'll know the problem lies in kitchenplan, not Chef or the RVM cookbook.

Right now, there's too many moving parts to determine if this is:

- A bug in the RVM cookbook
- A bug in Kitchenplan (or your particular configuration)
- A bug in Chef